# How to inside the children and childrens children elements of a list

Tags: jquery

Using this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fGTqF/ how can I show the sub-categories under the sub-categories of SALE? For example there are additional categories under SALE > BELTS, and SALE > ACCESSORIES but I can't figure how to target them to show. The code below will show the subcategories under SALE but I need it to show the subcategories of subcategories of SALE as well.

```
var $currentCategory = "Sale";
var s = $(".sideCatMenu a").filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === $currentCategory
}).addClass('active').eq(1).next().show()
```

Comment: Switching on the element text is not recommended, use IDs or classes or the modern data-attributes instead.

Comment: You may want to start by [tidying](http://infohound.net/tidy/) that HTML. Here's what it looks like after: http://jsfiddle.net/dandv/fGTqF/2/

Comment: If you need to show all subcategories, then don't hide them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The following will show all of the items after an anchor with the text `Sale`.

```
var $currentCategory = "Sale";
var s = $(".sideCatMenu a").filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === $currentCategory;
}).addClass("active").next().show();​​
```

What's probably unintentionally wrong with your code is that there is no second element with the text `Sale` (in that context). Keep in mind that `.eq()` uses zero-based indexes. So what you're probably looking for is (if you really want to limit your search):

```
var $currentCategory = "Sale";
var s = $(".sideCatMenu a").filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === $currentCategory;
}).addClass("active").eq(0).next().show();​​
```

The one thing that I don't understand, however, is why you would add the class and then limit the array, as that way all elements that matched the selector and filter would be red, but only one of them would have its items displayed. If you want to fix that, just use:

```
var $currentCategory = "Sale";
var s = $(".sideCatMenu a").filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === $currentCategory;
}).eq(0).addClass("active").next().show();​​
```

Comment: Sorry my Jquery skills are minimal right now. Neither example accomplished my objective to show all sub categories and subcategories of subcategories under SALE. They are initially hidden by a php script which i can't control because i only have access to the html not the php script. I am using JavaScript to show them how I desire though. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to display them when they are clicked, etc.?

Comment: No I'm trying to display them automatically when the page loads the currentCategory variable is determined by looking at the pages breadcrumb links actually.